# Move parent Control when Child Control Moves

Tags: c#, winforms

In a Winform I have a Panel and in it Lisview Control. If I Move the Panel then listview move. That is Ok. Listview tied to the Panel though it is Ok. But when i move Listview then only listview moves not panel. I want to make that Vice Versa. Question - how can I Move panel when i move Listview?

Comment: Are you talking about in designer mode? Or during runtime?

Comment: @icemanind during runtime.

Comment: Do you mean that the user is supposed to be able to move the controls at runtime, using the mouse? That is a fairly non-standard facility. I did write a program like that once, partially based on this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20483/Drag-and-Drop-Windows-Form-Controls-Design-UI-at-R Later I became aware of this article, but have never used the information in it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163871.aspx

Comment: How do you handle the movement in the first place? Modify that method so that you are moving the parent even if the user clicks and drags a child; the children will follow automatically. If you want better help than that, include a proper code example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Use move/LocationChanged event of listview to move the Panel or parent container.

change panel location proportionately to the change in location of listview Location